# Can I require per-user AuthenticationMethods when switching from a non-root user to a root user?

Tags: ssh, users, sshd, non-root-user, 2-factor-authentication

I currently SSH into a root user from another machine with an SSH key & 2FA, so I set `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive`.

If possible, I would like to be able to SSH into a non-root user and *switch* to the root user from here. I do not want to use an SSH key to do this but I would like to require 2FA when switching to the root user. In order to do this, I believe the root user needs `AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive`.

Is there a way for me to have `publickey,keyboard-interactive` for any access to the root user EXCEPT when it comes from this one particular non-root user, where I would want to just have `keyboard-interactive`?

Comment: You've not mentioned how you are switching users. Of you were to do it with sudo -i the user (not root) would be authenticated.  If configured with PAM, different users can be forced to use different authentication methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, no, you cannot make a per-user authentication choice *before* you identify and authenticate the user.